# Invalid package information to update from unbuntu 23.04 to 23.10

Tags: linux-headers

I'm using Ubuntu 23.04

I'm receiving this error when try to update:

Invalid package information After updating the package information, the essential package 'ubuntu-minimal' was not found. This may be because you do not have official mirrors listed in your software sources, or because the mirrors you are using are overloaded. See /etc/apt/sources.list to check the list of current software sources. In the case of overloaded mirrors, wait a few moments and try again.

Now I receive another error:

```
W:Updates from such a repository cannot be done securely and are therefore disabled by default. W:See the apt-secure(8) man page for repository creation and user configuration details. , E:The repository 'oem.archive.canonical.com groovy Release' does not have a Release file., W:Updates from such a repository cannot be done securely and are therefore disabled by definition., W:See apt -secure(8) manual page for repository creation and user configuration details., E:The repository 'dell.archive.canonical.com groovy Release' does not have an archive
```

Sudo apt update shows:

```
Reached:1 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian jammy InRelease
Reached:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://dell.archive.canonical.com groovy InRelease
Err:4 http://dell.archive.canonical.com groovy Release
  404 Not Found [IP: 185.125.189.10 80]
Reached:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic InRelease
Reached:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com groovy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updates from such a repository cannot be done securely and are therefore disabled by definition.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Please avoid commenting on your own question. [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1491468/edit) instead. Please show us the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: What OS are you even using?  `Err:4 http://dell.archive.canonical.com groovy Release` indicates you're on an ancient release of Ubuntu which reached End of Life in 2021.  You cannot use that repository as one of your sources and need to remove it from your /etc/apt/sources.list and any other file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ because that will not work in your upgrade anymore.  Dell uses the standard Ubuntu archives now.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Groovy Gorilla (20.10) has been End of Life since July 22 2021, so you will have to install a supported Ubuntu version, or upgrade to one, see howto here: [EOLUpgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades#Update_sources.list)

Answer (score 0):

What solved my issue was the advice shared by another user in this thread. They pointed out that the error message 'Err:4 http://dell.archive.canonical.com groovy Release' indicated that I was using an outdated release of Ubuntu that reached its End of Life in 2021. To resolve the problem, I had to remove this outdated repository from my /etc/apt/sources.list and any other files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/. It's important to note that Dell now uses the standard Ubuntu archives for their support, and this change is crucial for the upgrade process to work smoothly."

Feel free to use this response to help others who might encounter a similar issue.

Thank you guy's